# Avoid caching files inside web folder

Tags: symfony, caching, ffmpeg, browser-cache

I have a real time application working with Symfony 4 and ffmpeg. It works great in development environment, but it hangs on production because the cache.

Through ffmpeg, I write a mpd file from a RTSP stream in my /public/build/video folder.

I need to avoid caching this mpd because it always changes while the real time video is displayed (ffmpeg is running on background).

Please, could you help me to exclude "/public/build/video" folder and its content to be cachable.

Find attached a screenshot:

[image: Browser network cached resources]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation of the header Cache-Control you should try using `Cache-Control: no-cache`. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control)

Answer (score 0):

What about deleting the line containing :

```
#$kernel->loadClassCache();  // <-- comment out this line
```

in your front controller.